# iFrame tabbing within frame/pop-up window

Tags: user-interface, iframe

As shown in the following example, I would like to restrict the tab key behavior to just this frame with links.

http://jsfiddle.net/zFXNM/

```
tabindex ="1"
```

I do NOT want the tab to go the URL other items in the browser.

For example, the "Compose Mail" in Gmail does this already. I observed 3 usages of "tabindex=-1" within the JS.

Comment: We could maintain a tuple of first and last links on the page. When the user puts the last's link on focus. We set a toggle 

Whenever the last-link loses focus, we could set the focus on the first-link and hence the tab action.

I am still looking for examples to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure JavaScript, I have figured out a solution for this issue. The idea is whenever the page is loaded we determine the first and last links, then we prevent the tab default action and jump to the first link from the last tab.

```
if (activeElement.id == lastHrefID) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById(firstHrefID).focus();
}
```

A working solution is available at : https://jsfiddle.net/srirammac/95sv63s7/